# ios 7 when hide tabbar only in landscape view some space remaining black

Tags: ios7, uitabbar

In my app in portrait view tabbar is show and for landscape view it set as hidden, this working in ios6 smoothly but for iOS7 in Landscape view tabbar is hidden but its space is remaining as it is. Following my code.

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(![UICommonUtils isiPad]){

            if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

                [UICommonUtils hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];

            } else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

                [UICommonUtils showTabBar:self.tabBarController];
            }
      }
}
```

**Hide Tabbar**

```
+(void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *)tabbarcontroller
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    float fHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    if(  UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) )
    {
        fHeight = screenRect.size.width;
    }

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
}
```

**Show Tabbar**

```
+(void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float fHeight = screenRect.size.height - 49.0;

    if(  UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) )
    {
        fHeight = screenRect.size.width - 49.0;
    }
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following line of the code in `viewDidLoad` method :

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) 
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```